# MySQL 5.7.14 - CASE statement with date INTERVAL < NOW() throwing an error

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL select that is throwing an error in the CASE statement.

The section can be one of five values. I want to test if today's date (NOW) is less than the person's date of birth plus x years. The column dob is type DATE.

```
SELECT ca_id, cad_id, section, dob, 
    CASE 
        WHEN section LIKE '%Joey%' AND ((dob, INTERVAL 6 YEAR) < NOW()) THEN '1' 
        WHEN section LIKE '%Joey%' AND ((dob, INTERVAL 7 YEAR) < NOW()) THEN '2' 
        WHEN section LIKE '%Joey%' THEN '3' 
    ELSE '0' 
    END AS milestoneBracket
```

The error:

> SQLException in getAttendance: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') < NOW()) THEN '1'  WHEN section LIKE '%Joey%' AND ((dob, INTERVAL 7 YEAR) < NO' at line 1

Comment: You're missing the calls to `DATE_ADD()`: `DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL 6 YEAR)`

Comment: I consider this like a typo, you just left out the obvious calls. The question doesn't serve any lasting purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is a `Date Add` function call in your SQL query

```
SELECT ca_id, cad_id, section, dob, 
    CASE
        WHEN section LIKE '%Joey%' AND (DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL 6 YEAR) < NOW()) THEN '1'
        WHEN section LIKE '%Joey%' AND (DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL 7 YEAR) < NOW()) THEN '2' 
        WHEN section LIKE '%Joey%' THEN '3' 
    ELSE '0' 
    END AS milestoneBracket
```